I have 2 lazyrows with cards , scrolling first is smooth , but scrolling the 2nd one starts recomposition and hangs the row
Jetpack compose
In my app's homescreen there are 2 lazyrows containing same itemCards and same content , when testing on my phone when i scroll right on the first row its smooth and ok but when i start scrolling on 2nd row , the row hangs for a second or two then it compiles and is smooth again , how can i make these two optimised , like i dont want recomposition on 2nd row as 1st row has already composed same content.
Heres some related code:
@Immutable
data class itemData(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val soldBy: String,
    val stars : Int,
    val description: String,
    val painter: Painter,
    val originalPrice: Double,
    val salePrice: Double
)

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
    ) {
        items(SampleItems.size) { item ->
            SaleItemCard(item = SampleItems[item], onClickToDetailScreen = onClickToDetailScreen)
        }
    }
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        LazyRow(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            items(SampleItems.size, key = { SampleItems[it].id }) { item ->
                SaleItemCard(
                    item = SampleItems[item],
                    onClickToDetailScreen = onClickToDetailScreen
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


as you can see i tried using keys or @immutable but still same issue

Simplify design or optimize code. It should not generally lag and cant explain in deep as you have not provided design composable code

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
